# ANTLR's Parsing with SLL predication mode

Tags: java, c#, parsing, antlr4

I am parsing java source files ([Java Source Files](https://github.com/neiljbrown/java9-examples/tree/master/src/test/java/com/neiljbrown/examples/java9)) by using Grammar of Java9 in c#.

When i try to parse it with LL predication mode, It work fines but when i try to parse same java files with SLL predication mode, it shows below errors on some of lines.

> line 27:56 mismatched input ';' expecting '.'
> line 64:78 mismatched input ';' expecting '.'
> line 72:78 mismatched input ';' expecting '.'
> line 102:46 mismatched input ';' expecting '.'

or

> line 19:0 extraneous input 'import' expecting {, 'abstract', 'class', 'enum', 'final', 'interface', 'private', 'protected', 'public', 'static', 'strictfp', ';', '@'}

Thats how i am trying to parse java file

```
  AntlrFileStream stream = new AntlrFileStream(file);
  ITokenSource lexer = new Java9Lexer(stream);
  ITokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
  Java9Parser parser = new Java9Parser(tokens);
  parser.Interpreter.PredictionMode = PredictionMode.SLL;
  IParseTree tree = parser.compilationUnit();
```

What changes in grammer would resolve this issue. I can't apply LL predication mode because it parse source files too slow.

Comment: Interesting to see if you get SLL working. But, I don't think this will solve the slow parse speed you are noticing. Java9 (or Java8) is from the spec, which is not optimized for speed. A good portion of the time is just due to the size of the parse tree produced, but it's not strictly proportional, so it's likely there's something else. For comparison, try parsing with Parr's Java grammar, which is optimized. For CollectionStaticFactoryMethodsTest.java, it parses in 10s for Java9, 0.1s with Parr's Java. All your test files seem to parse fine in Parr's grammar.

Comment: @kaby76 Thanks for input. I have tried parsing test file using Parr's grammar https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antlr/codebuff/master/grammars/org/antlr/codebuff/Java.g4. There is performance improvement but still getting errors on some of lines.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using the grammar from old Codebuff?  The maintained version of Parr's grammar for Java is at https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/java/java.

Comment: Thanks @kaby76 it worked and performance is much better. Just need to know one thing, is there any way that i can get updated expressions or tokens of java9? so i can add them in same grammar?

Comment: If you wanted to update Parr's grammar with the Java9 updates, you have to modify the grammar yourself. FYI, I am working on a tool that will automatically modify the spec grammar, whatever version, for the optimizations Parr added, but it's a several months away.

Comment: @kaby76 Hi, any idea about this question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62666037/antlr-visitor-class-is-returning-null-for-parse-tree-in-c-sharp

Comment: @AtifHasan if you are going to improve fast java grammar for java9 support please suggest a pull request to the official grammars repository.